# TM Package in R to clean up text

Tags: r, nlp, tm

I am trying to clean up my text corpus using the TM package in R however I keep getting this error :

```
no applicable method for 'removePunctuation' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

My data is made of chat logs read from a text file and looks like this in R:

```
     V1
1   In the process
2   Sorry I had to step away for a moment.
3   I am getting an error page that says QB is currently unavailable.
4   That link gives me the same error message.
```

I use:

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(text,
                          control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                         stopwords = TRUE))
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

Seems like I wasnt supposed to feed a data frame into the function but how else can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: you can also try the qdap package that does similar things to tm, some are simpler. https://github.com/trinker/qdap take a look at the readme

Comment: Can you describe what you want the output to be?

Answer (score 1):

As @Martin Bel pointed out [qdap version 1.1.0](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/qdap-1-1-0-released-on-cran/) can do this as well.  I've added a bit of support to qdap to be more compatible with the tm package including a `tdm` function that would work well here:

**First read in your data (I added colons):**

```
library(qdap)
dat <- read.transcript(text="ID    V1
1   In the process
2   Sorry I had to step away for a moment.
3   I am getting an error page that says QB is currently unavailable.
4   That link gives me the same error message.", header=TRUE, sep="   ")
```

**# To make a term document matrix:**

```
tdm(dat$V1, id(dat), stopwords=tm::stopwords("en"))
```

**# To do the same thing with the tm package:**

```
TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(dat[, 1])),
    control = list(
        removePunctuation = TRUE,
        stopwords = TRUE
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, the quickest way is to use `DataframeSource` to make a corpus object, then make a term doc matrix from that. Using your example:

Let's input the data...

```
Text <- readLines(n=4)
In the process
Sorry I had to step away for a moment.
I am getting an error page that says QB is currently unavailable.
That link gives me the same error message.

df <- data.frame(V1 = Text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And now convert the data frame to Term Document Matrix...

```
require(tm)
mycorpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(df))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mycorpus, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE, stopwords = TRUE))
```

Now inspect the output...

```
inspect(tdm)
   A term-document matrix (14 terms, 4 documents)

Non-/sparse entries: 15/41
Sparsity           : 73%
Maximal term length: 11 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

             Docs
Terms         1 2 3 4
  away        0 1 0 0
  currently   0 0 1 0
  error       0 0 1 1
  getting     0 0 1 0
  gives       0 0 0 1
  link        0 0 0 1
  message     0 0 0 1
  moment      0 1 0 0
  page        0 0 1 0
  process     1 0 0 0
  says        0 0 1 0
  sorry       0 1 0 0
  step        0 1 0 0
  unavailable 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: This looks to have no substantive difference from the answer I give using tm.

Comment: Key difference is you have `VectorSource` and I have `DataframeSource`

Comment: In practical terms what's the difference between a vector and a single column dataframe?

Comment: Practically, very little.  Key difference is style.

Comment: I get `Error: all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id", "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE` when I run `mycorpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(df))`. Any guesses what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to unpack the text from the data frame, by doing `text[,1]`:

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(text[,1],
                          control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                         stopwords = TRUE))
```

Comment: hm, I tried that and now I get this error : `no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "factor"`

Comment: Urgh, this is one of the most annoying defaults in `R`. Try `as.vector(text[,1])`

Comment: If that doesn't work, read in your text file again, and give an extra argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to whatever function you used to read in the file.

Comment: i get this now: `no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: Ah. Since it's not expecting a vector of strings, you may need to use a special reader function. I haven't used the `tm` package before, but  the vignette (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf) indicates you could try `readPlain`?